# Controller (web request/antMatcher) security vs method(service) level security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring Security I see URL's secured with:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

I also see that there is method level security:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

Are the `antMatchers` used to secure the URL while the `@PreAuthorize` used to secure interfaces?

If the `antMatcher` secures the URL that calls the interface already, then why the need to separately secure the interface method?

Could you use method level security on the controller like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/dashboard/person")
public String findEvent(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
....
```

Comment: Question: what happens when you rename the endpoint, or worse - reuse it with the different URL? This exact issue has historically been the cause many issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Web security and method security are two different ways to secure your application, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-web-xml):

> **Why not just use web.xml security?**
>
> Let’s assume you’re developing an enterprise application based on Spring. There are four security concerns you typically need to address: authentication, web request security, service layer security (i.e. your methods that implement business logic), and domain object instance security (i.e. different domain objects have different permissions). With these typical requirements in mind:
>
> [...]
>
> 2. *Web request security:* The servlet specification provides an approach to secure your request URIs. However, these URIs can only be expressed in the servlet specification’s own limited URI path format. Spring Security provides a far more comprehensive approach. For instance, you can use Ant paths or regular expressions, you can consider parts of the URI other than simply the requested page (e.g. you can consider HTTP GET parameters) and you can implement your own runtime source of configuration data. This means your web request security can be dynamically changed during the actual execution of your webapp.
> 3. *Service layer and domain object security:* The absence of support in the servlet specification for services layer security or domain object instance security represent serious limitations for multi-tiered applications. Typically developers either ignore these requirements, or implement security logic within their MVC controller code (or even worse, inside the views). There are serious disadvantages with this approach:
>
>    a. *Separation of concerns:* Authorization is a crosscutting concern and should be implemented as such. MVC controllers or views implementing authorization code makes it more difficult to test both the controller and authorization logic, more difficult to debug, and will often lead to code duplication.
>
>    b. *Support for rich clients and web services:* If an additional client type must ultimately be supported, any authorization code embedded within the web layer is non-reusable. It should be considered that Spring remoting exporters only export service layer beans (not MVC controllers). As such authorization logic needs to be located in the services layer to support a multitude of client types.
>
>    c. *Layering issues:* An MVC controller or view is simply the incorrect architectural layer to implement authorization decisions concerning services layer methods or domain object instances. Whilst the Principal may be passed to the services layer to enable it to make the authorization decision, doing so would introduce an additional argument on every services layer method. A more elegant approach is to use a ThreadLocal to hold the Principal, although this would likely increase development time to a point where it would become more economical (on a cost-benefit basis) to simply use a dedicated security framework.
>
>    d. *Authorisation code quality:* It is often said of web frameworks that they "make it easier to do the right things, and harder to do the wrong things". Security frameworks are the same, because they are designed in an abstract manner for a wide range of purposes. Writing your own authorization code from scratch does not provide the "design check" a framework would offer, and in-house authorization code will typically lack the improvements that emerge from widespread deployment, peer review and new versions.

Spring Security recommends method security, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching):

> **10.1.4 Request Matching and HttpFirewall**
>
> [...]
>
> In practice we recommend that you use method security at your service layer, to control access to your application, and do not rely entirely on the use of security constraints defined at the web-application level. URLs change and it is difficult to take account of all the possible URLs that an application might support and how requests might be manipulated. You should try and restrict yourself to using a few simple ant paths which are simple to understand. Always try to use a "deny-by-default" approach where you have a catch-all wildcard ( / or ) defined last and denying access.
>
> Security defined at the service layer is much more robust and harder to bypass, so you should always take advantage of Spring Security’s method security options.

Spring Security recommends applying method security at the service layer rather than on individual web controllers, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-method-security-in-web-context):

> **I have added Spring Security’s  element to my application context but if I add security annotations to my Spring MVC controller beans (Struts actions etc.) then they don’t seem to have an effect.**
>
> [...]
>
> Generally we would recommend applying method security at the service layer rather than on individual web controllers.

Comment: Nice and comprehensive answer. What does ant in antMatcher stand for?

Comment: @AlGrant antMatcher means a path matcher that uses a syntax for matching paths that was first made common with [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/).