# Check session value before controller declaration

Tags: spring, session

Is there a way in Spring to check if a session variable is set and has a specific value before accessing a controller?

The point to restrict access to a whole controller unless a specific session variable is set.

The bold and italic line of code DOES NOT exist, its just something i made up to explain my thoughts.

Example code for explanation:

```
@Controller
***@SessionCheckValue(session.getAttribute("value")=="true" else redirect_to_some_page)***
public class MainController {

  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }


}
```

Comment: It all depends. Do you need it for multiple controllers/methods or just in a single method.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security), you could add a `@PreAuthorize` annotation to your controller* class in which logic is performed, such as:

```
@PreAuthorize("@someBean.isUserVerified()")
// or
@PreAuthorize("#{T(com.package.someClass).someStaticAuthenticationMethod()}")
```

Or you could write your own AOP advice using AspectJ. If you don't mind putting the annotations on a method level instead of class level, [Spring AOP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop) is also an option. Though I would be cautious when writing your own *security* implementation.

Furthermore, Spring supports both method security (as described above) as well as web security. In web security, the authentication+authorization is performed on the HTTP(S) endpoints rather than on a class/method. A comparison can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358424/antmatcher-vs-method-security).

*Note: Spring recommends adding class/method security on the service layer rather than on the controller layer, as multiple controllers may refer to the same service.